# python docker image versions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm on mac with python version 3.7.9. I tried to find save python version image on docker hub, but they only have either 3.7 or 3.7.10. Does 3.7 include 3.7.9 as well? If so why 3.7.10 stands alone by itself?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just checked recent uploads that happen to be 3.7 and 3.10. If you search by version number you would also find 3.7.9

https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.7.9/images/sha256-21a2e2a55acae91d74e351ee3c4edaf25ec3236b8501907e827c534d0f3f72fb?context=explore

PS : The best way to check if a version exists or not, just do the docker pull

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for gsb22. Was my first time trying to find a specific image version and i thought the ones listed under 'Descriptions' are the only ones available. After reminded by gsb22, I found there's a tiny Filter Tag box under the tags section that I can search for specific tags.

Comment: I think you have used answer section to add the comment. You can move this to comment section on my answer. Also, if this has resolved your issue, feel free mark this as answer.